# Saving array to CoreData Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, persistence

I would like to save this kind of `arrays` with `Core Data`:

```
let crypto1 = Cryptos(name: "Bitcoin", code: "bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", placeholder: "BTC Amount", amount: "0.0")
let crypto2 = Cryptos(name: "Bitcoin Cash", code: "bitcoinCash", symbol: "BCH", placeholder: "BCH Amount", amount: "0.0")
```

Is that even possible?

I know I can create an array to save like that...

```
let name = "Bitcoin"
let code = "bitcoin"
let symbol = "BTC"
let placeholder = "BTC Amount"
let amount = "0.0"
let cryptos = CryptoArray(context: PersistenceService.context)
cryptos.name = name
cryptos.code = code
cryptos.symbol = symbol
cryptos.placeholder = placeholder
cryptos.amount = amount
crypto.append(cryptos)
PersistenceService.saveContext()
```

...but this seems pretty inconvenient when a theoretical infinite number of arrays will be created by the user.

What would be the best way for me to save data, load it, edit it and delete it?

Comment: Don't save an array. Save multiple instances of a Core Data entity.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot for answering! This is interesting but I don't think I completely understand why. What would this mean in my case? (I just started Core Data, please forgive any blunder if I don't see the obvious here)

Comment: Each instance of `Cryptos` would be mapped to a Core Data entity instance. (In fact, your `Cryptos` object could well be your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a question for a tutorial rather than a straight forward answer. I suggest you give some time to read about `CoreData`. Having said that, your question sounds generic, "Saving array to CoreData in Swift", so I guess it doesn't hurt to explain a simple implementation step by step:

**Step 1: Create your model file (.xcdatamodeld)**

In Xcode, `file - new - file - iOS` and choose `Data Model`

**Step 2: Add entities**

Select the file in Xcode, find and click on `Add Entity`, name your entity (`CryptosMO` to follow along), click on `Add Attribute` and add the fields you like to store. (`name, code, symbol...` all of type `String` in this case). I'll ignore everything else but `name` for ease.

**Step 3 Generate Object representation of those entities (NSManagedObject)**

In Xcode, `Editor - Create NSManagedObject subclass` and follow the steps.

**Step 4 Lets create a clone of this subclass**

NSManagedObject is not thread-safe so lets create a struct that can be passed around safely:

```
struct Cryptos {
    var reference: NSManagedObjectID! // ID on the other-hand is thread safe. 

    var name: String // and the rest of your properties
}
```

**Step 5: CoreDataStore**

Lets create a store that gives us access to `NSManagedObjectContext`s:

```
class Store {
    private init() {}
    private static let shared: Store = Store()

    lazy var container: NSPersistentContainer = {

        // The name of your .xcdatamodeld file.
        guard let url = Bundle().url(forResource: "ModelFile", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Create the .xcdatamodeld file with the correct name !!!")
            // If you're setting up this container in a different bundle than the app,
            // Use Bundle(for: Store.self) assuming `CoreDataStore` is in that bundle.
        }
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ModelFile")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, _ in }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true

        return container
    }()

    // MARK: APIs

    /// For main queue use only, simple rule is don't access it from any queue other than main!!!
    static var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext { return shared.container.viewContext }

    /// Context for use in background.
    static var newContext: NSManagedObjectContext { return shared.container.newBackgroundContext() }
}
```

`Store` sets up a persistent container using your `.xcdatamodeld` file.

**Step 6: Data source to fetch these entities**

Core Data comes with `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch entities from a context that allows extensive configuration, here is a simple implementation of a data source support using this controller.

```
class CryptosDataSource {

    let controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>
    let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = CryptosMO.fetchRequest()

    let defaultSort: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(CryptosMO.name), ascending: false)

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor] = []) {
        var sort: [NSSortDescriptor] = sortDescriptors
        if sort.isEmpty { sort = [defaultSort] }

        request.sortDescriptors = sort

        controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    }

    // MARK: DataSource APIs

    func fetch(completion: ((Result) -> ())?) {
        do {
            try controller.performFetch()
            completion?(.success)
        } catch let error {
            completion?(.fail(error))
        }
    }

    var count: Int { return controller.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0 }

    func anyCryptos(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cryptos {
        let c: CryptosMO = controller.object(at: indexPath) as! CryptosMO
        return Cryptos(reference: c.objectID, name: c.name)
    }
}
```

All we need from an instance of this class is, number of objects, `count` and item at a given indexPath. Note that the data source returns the struct `Cryptos` and not an instance of `NSManagedObject`.

**Step 7: APIs for add, edit and delete**

Lets add this apis as an extension to `NSManagedObjectContext`:
But before that, these actions may succeed or fail so lets create an enum to reflect that:

```
enum Result {
    case success, fail(Error)
}
```

The APIs:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    // MARK: Load data

    var dataSource: CryptosDataSource { return CryptosDataSource(context: self) }

    // MARK: Data manupulation

    func add(cryptos: Cryptos, completion: ((Result) -> ())?) {
        perform {
            let entity: CryptosMO = CryptosMO(context: self)
            entity.name = cryptos.name
            self.save(completion: completion)
        }
    }

    func edit(cryptos: Cryptos, completion: ((Result) -> ())?) {
        guard cryptos.reference != nil else { 
            print("No reference")
            return 
        }
        perform {
            let entity: CryptosMO? = self.object(with: cryptos.reference) as? CryptosMO
            entity?.name = cryptos.name
            self.save(completion: completion)
        }
    }

    func delete(cryptos: Cryptos, completion: ((Result) -> ())?) {
        guard cryptos.reference != nil else { 
            print("No reference")
            return 
        }
        perform {
            let entity: CryptosMO? = self.object(with: cryptos.reference) as? CryptosMO
            self.delete(entity!)
            self.save(completion: completion)
        }
    }

    func save(completion: ((Result) -> ())?) {
        do {
            try self.save()
            completion?(.success)
        } catch let error {
            self.rollback()
            completion?(.fail(error))
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 8: Last step, use case**

To fetch the stored data in main queue, use `Store.viewContext.dataSource`.
To add, edit or delete an item, decide if you'd like to do on main queue using  `viewContext`, or from any arbitrary queue (even main queue) using `newContext` or a temporary background context provided by Store container using `Store.container.performInBackground...` which will expose a context.
e.g. adding a cryptos:

```
let cryptos: Cryptos = Cryptos(reference: nil, name: "SomeName")
Store.viewContext.add(cryptos: cryptos) { result in
   switch result {
   case .fail(let error): print("Error: ", error)
   case .success: print("Saved successfully")
   }
}
```

Simple `UITableViewController` that uses the cryptos data source:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let dataSource: CryptosDataSource = Store.viewContext.dataSource

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellId", for: indexPath)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cryptos: Cryptos = dataSource.anyCryptos(at: indexPath)
        // TODO: Configure your cell with cryptos values.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the method to fetch the data back and use it in my tableView cells at indexPath I don't know what to do with `Store.viewContext.dataSource` and what it returns

Comment: I'm kind of lost to get the array back and use it for my cells here

Comment: `Store.viewContext.dataSource` returns a data source instance which but I've missed one api for fetching. I'll add it on edit

Comment: I've also added some code to show how to use the data source at the end.

Comment: I won't lie I'm completely lost here haha, I shouldn't have been learning tableViews and CoreData at the same time, I can't get to understand when to fetch and how to use the method. Is there any chance I might send you my files for review and you point to what I need to do with comments in the code? I really need to get it going by myself but the multiplicity of files and methods confuses me and I need guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot save arrays directly with CoreData, but you can create a function to store each object of an array. With [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) the whole process is quite simple:

```
let dataStack: DataStack = {
    let dataStack = DataStack(xcodeModelName: "ModelName")
    do {
        try dataStack.addStorageAndWait()
    } catch let error {
        print("Cannot set up database storage: \(error)")
    }
    return dataStack
}()

func addCrypto(name: String, code: String, symbol: String, placeholder: String, amount: Double) {
    dataStack.perform(asynchronous: { transaction in
        let crypto = transaction.create(Into<Crypto>())
        crypto.name = name
        crypto.code = code
        crypto.symbol = symbol
        crypto.placeholder = placeholder
        crypto.amount = amount
    }, completion: { _ in })
}
```

You can show the objects within a `UITableViewController`. CoreStore is able to automatically update the table whenever database objects are added, removed or updated:

```
class CryptoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let monitor = dataStack.monitorList(From<Crypto>(), OrderBy(.ascending("name")), Tweak({ fetchRequest in
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    }))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Register self as observer to monitor
        self.monitor.addObserver(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.monitor.numberOfObjects()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CryptoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CryptoTableViewCell
        let crypto = self.monitor[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.update(crypto)
        return cell
    }

}

// MARK: - ListObjectObserver

extension CryptoTableViewController : ListObjectObserver {

    // MARK: ListObserver

    func listMonitorWillChange(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func listMonitorDidChange(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func listMonitorWillRefetch(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>) {
    }

    func listMonitorDidRefetch(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: ListObjectObserver

    func listMonitor(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>, didInsertObject object: Switch, toIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    func listMonitor(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>, didDeleteObject object: Switch, fromIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    func listMonitor(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>, didUpdateObject object: Crypto, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CryptoTableViewCell {
            cell.update(object)
        }
    }

    func listMonitor(_ monitor: ListMonitor<Crypto>, didMoveObject object: Switch, fromIndexPath: IndexPath, toIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [fromIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [toIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

}
```

Assuming that you have a `CryptoTableViewCell` with the function `update` registered to the `CryptoTableViewController`.

Comment: This looks awesome! Would it be suited to use with a tableView and easily edit/delete the arrays at indexPath?

Comment: Yes, CoreStore provides special functions to do this. I extended my answer accordingly.